# How can I start xfreerdp on localhost?

Tags: x11, xorg, kali-linux, freerdp, xfreerdp

I've installed Kali sana on my Android tablet -lenovo a5500-hv- using Linux deploy and I use either vnc or xrdp to connect it to my Android and have ability to use GUI.

But they don't support audio and I can't use music on my Linux , so I search for a better solution.

I've just installed xfreerdp on both my Linux and Android. Now I want to start it but I don't know how. I already read man xfreerdp but I didn't understand it very well.

My username is : android
And the password is : changeme // however I'll change it as soon as possible

Would you please give me code to run it? By the way my screen size is 1280x720
// both Kali and Android are in the same device but I use vnc app on my Android to use my Linux.